# Android phone USB tethering to ACER netbook

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, android, tethering, canon-pixma

I have an older netbook ACER Aspire One zg5 running Peppermint 9 with dead WiFi card, so I use an android phone (Motorola one) to tether via USB to ACER netbook, everything  works with no issues (**almost**). The problem is to install my printer (canon pixma mg4250) connected via WiFi, the drivers are installed (for printer and for scanner), scanner driver is **scangearmp** BUT when I run scangearmp command the program can not find any printer/scanner in the network, I refreshed few times **update scanner list** but no success the canon pixma is not visible.
My main laptop (OS Xubuntu 16.04.6 detect the printer/scanner without issues).
Maybe some configuration on android phone USB tethering and/or netbook missing ?
Thanks in advace, vladi

Comment: Are you USB tethering the WiFi - only situation where it could (eventually) detect the printer in the same network - or the mobile connection - couldn't possibly work -?

Comment: So you're getting to the Internet via the phone.  How is the phone getting to the Internet, WiFi link to your router or a mobile data connection?  If it's a mobile data connection, the router and printer aren't part of the picture (GabrielaGarcia's point).

Comment: Phone gets internet via **WiFi**, the same network as the printer, **mobile data connection is off**, then phone connected to netbook via USB.